# What is the usual answer to the question "how do you feel"?

Tags: phrase-choice

Tell me please what someone is supposed to answer when asked *how do you feel*?

Comment: Why do you think there is a single answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When asked "how do you feel?" a person may choose to give a truthful answer (hot, tired, nauseous, shaken, bored, excited, etc) or they might just say "Fine, thanks".